# How to interpret this array indexing in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I wanted to interpret array indexing in the following code snippet. What does `State[t,Con]` mean, where `Con` itself is an array?

```
for t in range(T):  # 0 .. T-1
    State[t+1] = Bool[:, sum(Pow * State[t,Con],1)].diagonal()
```

And `Con` is given as below (where N>K):

```
Con = apply_along_axis(random.permutation, 1, tile(range(N), (N,1) ))[:, 0:K]
```

Answer (score 1):

`Con` is a `(N,K)` array of integers.

`State` presumably is `(T,N)` array.

`State[t,Con]` will be a `(N,K)` array of values selected from the `t` row of `State`.  Since `Con` has repeats, some values of the `State` row will be repeated.

```
`Bool[:, sum(Pow * State[t,Con],1)].diagonal()`
```

It then does a element by element multiplication with `Pow` (also a (N,K) array, or something compatible).  Then sum over the last axis (columns), giving a `N,)` array (N element vector).  Then select those columns from array `Bool` (a `(N,N)` array?).  Finally get the main diagonal - again N values.

The last step is to assign those values to the `t+1` row of `State`.

Comment: Do you know how to translate this to matlab?

Comment: I'd have to experiment on my copy of Octave.